# Heap memory consumed more than committed memory

Tags: java, heap-memory, jprofiler

Can heap memory increase beyond the cap of -Xmx memory? I have -Xmx set to 1G. The profiling screenshot captured from JProfile shows the heap growing beyond 1G and sometime doubling to 2G. What then is the meaning of -Xmx ?

[image: JProfiler Output]

Comment: Xmx if for the heap, yes. Aren't you mistaking the lines? The Blue one is for the heap and only surpasses the 1GB threshold once.

Comment: @alex Well I had a instance when the blue line approached 2G. That worried me.

Comment: Maybe a badly entered parameter? These are some examples from another post: -Xmx1024k -Xmx512m -Xmx8g. command and number stick together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script that started Glassfish overrode the -Xmx parameter.The -Xmx parameter was set to 2G which explains the graph.